# RDP in windows server 2008 R2 shows no desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, desktop

Going by RDP to Windows Server 2008 R2, after "preparing your desktop" nothing happens. Just a blue screen (desktop solid color) and nothing else. No start menu, no icons. If I'll CTRL+ALT+END I'm able to open EXPLORER.EXE, and the desktop is back to normal, else, I'm just stuck with the blue screen. Does someone knows anything about this issue?

Comment: Is RDP enabled in the server?

Comment: Of course. I just told you I'm going by RDP on server, but I have to manually open the explorer.exe from task manager in order to see my desktop

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem with your profile on the server. Have you contacted your server administrator?

Comment: I'm the server admin, and I don't know what to do to solve it. And I also removed the profile, but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you try to modify the RDP settings before connecting to the server?

Comment: Have you logged out properly? Have you rebooted the server?

Comment: i haven't modified RDP settings, I can't connect to all other servers but one..

Comment: @LPChip I did rebooted many times.